# How to write selling price on the next line of Regular price in wordpress woocommerce website?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have uploaded some products in my portal. While uploading the products I have mentioned Regular price and then Selling Price. The prices are shown on the same row/line. If the price are longer in length, it is overflowing in the next line. I want to display regular price and selling price on the separate lines.

Your Help will be appreciable.
Thanks

Website Link is : http://gotodukan.com/shop/

PHP Code:

```
 <?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product;
?>

<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <div class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

CSS Code:

```
.product-meta {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.product-meta .name {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.3;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.product-meta .price {
  color: #f2434a;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
}
.product-meta .price > .amount,
.product-meta .price ins {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.product-meta .price del {
  color: #9c9c9c;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.rtl .product-meta .price del {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this css:

```
.product-meta .price del {
  color: #9c9c9c;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

to this

```
.product-meta .price del {
  color: #9c9c9c;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  display:block !important;

}
```

Hope this helps.